# Is it possible for Capistrano to only link a file on some servers?

Tags: ruby, capistrano

If I have a something like this:

config/deploy/production.rb:

```rb
server myserver1 roles: %i[app web db]
server myserver2 roles: %i[app web db]
server myutilserver1 roles: %[util]
```

config/deploy.rb:

```rb
append :linked_files, 'all_servers_file.yml'
append :linked_files, 'util_server_file.yml'
```

Is there some way to rework this so that `util_server_file.yml` is only linked on `myutilserver1`, but `all_servers_file.yml` still goes to all servers? Or is this an all-or-nothing situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably define extra roles for those servers

```
server myserver1 roles: %i[app web db utils_server_file]
server myserver2 roles: %i[app web db all_servers_file]
```

And then specify on which roles each task should run:

```
append :linked_files, 'all_servers_file.yml', roles: %i[all_servers_file]
append :linked_files, 'util_server_file.yml', roles: %i[utils_server_file]
```

This solution though seems hacku, and maybe there's a better way. But to know that - we'd need to know the context behing this particular files difference between two servers.